# ajax json query directly to python generated html gets undefined

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json

I've been struggling three weeks for now and I'm at the dead end. Sysadmins are s*tty developers :)

I'm trying to build lightweight cgi-bin python scripts to collect data and convert it into json format.
Then I use plain html page to make ajax query to python scripts to get data and draw my charts (periodically, people love real-time stuff)

These should be as light as possible, because they work on raspberry.

One of my python scripts that collects the data

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3
import gviz_api

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

connection = sqlite3.connect("templog.db")
connection.row_factory = dict_factory
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select temp, status from data where ID = (select MAX(ID) from data)")
# fetch all or one we'll go for all.
results = cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()

schema = {"temp": ("number", "temp"),"status": ("number", "status")}
data = results

# Loading it into gviz_api.DataTable
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(schema)
data_table.LoadData(data)
json = data_table.ToJSon(columns_order=("temp", "status"),order_by="temp")
#print results

#print "Content-type: application/json\n\n"
print "Content-type: application/json"
print

print json
```

This works like a charm when I open it up on my browser and it gives me what I need in corrent format for Google jsapi

```
{"rows":[{"c":[{"v":21.062},{"v":0}]}],"cols":[{"type":"number","id":"temp","label":"temp"},{"type":"number","id":"status","label":"status"}]}
```

Below is my html that needs the json data from python script to draw the chart

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

    function drawTable() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://192.168.1.123:8099/cgi-bin/test.py",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
          alert(jsonData);

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I got "undefined" alert when html is making ajax query directly to python script.

Then I copied json output 1:1 to plain static html file and replaced ajax URL to .html instead of dynamic .py, and it works.

My question is - are there some limitations for what I'm trying to do or is there something wrong with my code?

My code is based on examples
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/gviz_api_lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your javascript correctly, the responseText property is only set *after the request has completed*.  Normally, these things execute asynchronously, so you register a function to be called after the data has been received.  e.g.

```
function drawTable() {
  var drawChart = function(jsonData) {
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
  };

  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://192.168.1.123:8099/cgi-bin/test.py",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
  }).done(drawChart);

}
```

More examples can be found on in the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples).