# convert python sql list into dictionary

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

How to convert

```
cursor.execute("SELECT strftime('%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S', timestamp, 'localtime'), temp FROM data WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','-1 hours')")
# fetch all or one we'll go for all.
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results[:-1]:
row=results[-1]
rowstr="['{0}',{1}]\n".format(str(row[0]),str(row[1]))
temp_chart_table+=rowstr
```

result

```
['01.15.2015 21:38:52',21.812]
```

into dictionary output in form of:

```
[{timestamp:'01.15.2015 21:38:52',temp:21.812}]
```

**Edit**

This is fetchone sample I currenyly use and it works fine:

```
def get_avg():

    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("SELECT ROUND(avg(temp), 2.2) FROM data WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','-1 hour') AND timestamp<=datetime('now')")
    rowavg=curs.fetchone()
    #print rowavg
    #rowstrmin=format(str(rowavg[0]))
    #return rowstrmin
    **d = [{"avg":rowavg[0]}]**
    return d

    conn.close()

#print get_avg()
schema = {"avg": ("number", "avg")}
data = get_avg()
# Loading it into gviz_api.DataTable
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(schema)
data_table.LoadData(data)
json = data_table.ToJSon()
#print results

#print "Content-type: application/json\n\n"
print "Content-type: application/json"
print
print json
```

Then I make jQuery call and pass it into javascript and found help for that in here
[ajax json query directly to python generated html gets undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953036/ajax-json-query-directly-to-python-generated-html-gets-undefined)

Comment: that result doesn't seem right, shouldn't it be `[['01.15.2015 21:38:52',21.812]]` (double `[`, meaning list of lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT strftime('%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S', timestamp, 'localtime'), temp FROM data WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','-1 hours')")
# fetch all or one we'll go for all.
results = cursor.fetchall()
temp_chart_table = []
for row in results:
    temp_chart_table.append({'timestamp': row[0], 'temp': row[1]})
```

Comment: This gives me back where I was before

    [{'timestamp': u'01.15.2015 22:06:15', 'temp': 21.875}]

instead of

    [{timestamp: '01.15.2015 22:06:15', temp: 21.875}]

Comment: In Python, the keys must be strings: 'timestamp' and 'temp'.  The timestamp value with the "u" prefix means that the value is a Unicode string.  This is all good.

Comment: You are right!
It almost works, json format is okay now I get error at javascript level that says my timestamp cannot be sting :(
I have no idea howcome, it's okay if i skip json. I hate time conversions.
"Wrong type &lt;type 'unicode'&gt; when expected date". What does it want from me..initial question answered. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you are using `format` to write in the form of a string.

Note from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> it is not possible to use { and } as fill char while using the str.format() method

To make it **look** like a dictionary you can do

```
"[{timestamp:'%s',temp:%s}]\n"%(str(row[0]),str(row[1]))
```

But if you want to make it a dictionary then you will have to do

```
row_dic = [{'timestamp':row[0],'temp':row[1]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In most of the python database adapters you can use a `DictCursor` to retrieve records using an interface similar to the Python dictionaries instead of the tuples.

**Using psycopg2**:

```
>>> dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
>>> dict_cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES(%s, %s)",
...                  (100, "abc'def"))
>>> dict_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
>>> rec = dict_cur.fetchone()
>>> rec['id']
1
>>> rec['num']
100
>>> rec['data']
"abc'def"
```

**Using MySQLdb**:

```
>>> import MySQLdb 
>>> import MySQLdb.cursors 
>>> myDb = MySQLdb.connect(user='andy47', passwd='password', db='db_name', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) 
>>> myCurs = myDb.cursor() 
>>> myCurs.execute("SELECT columna, columnb FROM tablea") 
>>> firstRow = myCurs.fetchone() 
{'columna':'first value', 'columnb':'second value'}
```

Comment: MySQLdb has an analogous class:  `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` which you would use as:  `conn.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)` -- Or I suppose you could pass the cursor class (using the same keyword argument to the connection constructor).

Answer (score 0):

```
def stuffToDict(stuff):
    return {"timestamp":stuff[0],"temp":stuff[1]}
```

That would be a dictionary. The sample output you showed is a list of dictionaries, which can be achieved by putting square brackets around the dictionary. I don't know why you'd want that, though. Also, because of the missing quotes, it wasn't legal python syntax.

Comment: I'm trying to get proper format out of the result to throw it into Google gviz api, for visualization.

Comment: That is most likely JSON, which is what my function returns, if you `str()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQLdb's cursor library.

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_passwd, db=db_schema, port=db_port, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT timestamp, localtime, temp FROM data WHERE timestamp>datetime('now','-1 hours')")
# fetch all or one we'll go for all.
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Then you have access to the results as a dictionary:

```
>>> results['timestamp']
14146587
>>> results['localtime']
20:08:07
>>> results['temp']
temp_variable_whatever
```