# google visualization api json vs arraytodatatable in python, datatype nightmare

Tags: javascript, python, json, string, datetime

At first I created simple static google visualization page with python

source in python:

```
def print_graph_script(temp_table):

    # google chart snippet
    chart_code="""
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Temperature', 'Low', 'High'],
%s
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Temperature stats',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('temp_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>"""

    print chart_code % (temp_table)
```

and result in html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Time', 'Temperature', 'Low', 'High'],
['01.15.2015 22:23:53', 22.937, 20.0, 22.0],
['01.15.2015 23:23:43', 21.687, 20.0, 22.0]

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Temperature stats',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('temp_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

As it's seen, it works fine and passes timestamp in format '01.15.2015 23:23:43', which looks like a string to me.

Now I try to evolve and move to Json and this causes me headaches.

As Brent Washburne in [convert python sql list into dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971785/convert-python-sql-list-into-dictionary) posted, I create my dictionary accordingly

Result example:

```
[{'timestamp': u'01.15.2015 23:54:12', 'temp': 21.375}]
```

Now, when I pass it to gviz_api to turn it into json:

```
schema = {"timestamp": ("string", "timestamp"),"temp": ("number", "temp")}
data = temp_chart_table
# Loading it into gviz_api.DataTable
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(schema)
data_table.LoadData(data)
json = data_table.ToJSon()
```

I get similar result as with arraytodatatable:

```
[{"v":"01.15.2015 23:59:42"}]}]
```

Surprisingly, javascript doesn't like string anymore, and hits me with error:

> Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

There's little info on the internet, except some source codes.
I tried to change "string" to "datetime", as https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable suggests, but then I hit a brick wall with converting problems.

Why it doesn't like string date (in whatever form) anymore, like with arraytodatatable?
Or how can I go around the problem?

Comment: You have 3 different string formats representing dates here:  `'2015.01.15 23:54:12'`, `'01.15.2015 22:23:53'` and `"15.01.2015 23:59:42"` -- And none of them are standardized time formats as far as I can tell.  Why not use a standardized iso format and be done with it?

Comment: I use 
   `curs.execute("INSERT INTO data values (null, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?), (?))", (temp,pinstatus,low_limit,high_limit,lightstatus,balstatus,vvstatus,svstatus))` 
to insert timestamo into database, that should be "best practice" by my understanding.
`strftime` lets me to convert it into my region format and add missing GMT
That's my bad acctualy that those formats are messed up as you mentioned, copy-paste error. All of them should be "d.m.Y H:M:S", but google API eats all of them, no matter in what order they are. And only if I pass them as array.

Answer (score 0):

Another sleepless night directed me to https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html chapter 11.13.5.4. Default adapters and converters

It uses "detect_types" in connection header.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname,detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```

Apparently, that's what you need to get tour timestamp from database in format:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 16, 10, 43, 54, 193266)
```

instead of unicode string, as mentioned in my original question

Thanks for all help!